# SharePoint 2010 page with Silverlight prevent some js files from loading

Tags: javascript, silverlight, sharepoint

I deploy a custom aspx page to the layouts folder in SharePoint 2010. I use the default master page whihc includes some script-on-demand registrations (core.js, sp.js, etc.). If I have an empty page, all scripts load. However, if I put a silverlight object in the page none of the scripts load. What may cause the problem?